# LINQ queries always sort by primary key value even when orderby clause explicitly calls to sort with a different value

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-order-by

I am working on my first personal C# project and am incorporating LINQ to make queries against a SQL Server database. I am experiencing an issue with LINQ where queries always sort the records returned from the table according to their primary key value even though *orderby* clauses exist in the query.

My objective is to query a table that includes columns for first name and last name (both of type *varchar*); sort by first name; then sort by last name. The problem code consists of two sections. The first is the original query:

```
var dayShiftCrew =
            from information in context.EmployeeInformations
            where information.EmployeeShiftType.Shift == "Day" && information.EmployeePositionType.Position == "Crew"
            orderby information.EmployeeNamesAndNumber.FirstName, information.EmployeeNamesAndNumber.LastName
            select information.EmployeeNamesAndNumber;
```

The second part is a *foreach* statement that populates another table with the query results:

```
foreach (var employee in dayShiftCrew)
            {
                var position =
                    from selection in context.EmployeeInformations
                    where selection.EmployeeID == employee.EmployeeID
                    select selection.Position;

                string query2 = $@"USE Employees; INSERT INTO WeeklySchedule_{month}_{day}_{year} " +
                    @"(EmployeeID, Name, Position) VALUES " +
                    $@"({employee.EmployeeID}, '{employee.FirstName + (" ") + employee.LastName}', '{position.First()}');";

                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

When I view the destination table after it is populated, the records are not arranged according to the query's *orderby* clause. I have executed variations of this code multiple times, and each time the records appear in the same sequence. The sequence in the destination table matches the sequence in the original table, which leads me to think that either the query is sorting by the records' primary key value *or* is not sorting at all and simply returning the records in their original sequence.

I'm sure that there is something that I'm overlooking, but I have been experimenting for a while with this code and cannot find a solution to sort correctly. I have tried both kinds of syntax for LINQ queries; tried using one *orderby* rule instead of two; and rewrote lines for immediate instead of deferred execution.

Other specific details: The *from* clause refers to a table with a composite primary key that includes four foreign-key relationships. The query returns an *IQueryable* that contains the desired records, albeit in the wrong order. No exceptions are thrown at compile or runtime, and no other unexpected behavior is occurring apart from this.

Comment: If you query a table, without an order by, the database can return records in any order. But will usually return rows in the order of an index. A table can have a clustered index, meaning that the rows of the table are sorted the same as this index. A primary key is usually clustered. This includes your query of your destination table.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman this was a helpful response; I am relatively new to working with databases and this project is a way for me to get hands on experience. I looked up clustered indexes and discovered this was why I was seeing the same sequence every time. All I needed to do was revise the interpolated string so that the new primary key simply increments for each record. Now the sorting works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: @MegaZeo165, actually you can insert records into other database in one LINQ query, but it needs third party extension, If you interested I can propose solution.

Comment: *`INSERT INTO WeeklySchedule_{month}_{day}_{year}`* - you are storing in a table name information that you should store in a column, and are hence dooming yourself to have to repeat this (ugly, insecure) pattern any time you want to work with entities associated with this table. As is your code will fall apart as soon as you get your first person named O'Leary, and really cause a problem when Bobby Tables turns up

Comment: @CaiusJard The first three parameters in the string can only receive arguments passed from a MonthlyCalendar control (app uses WinForms). All fields in the app that can accept text input are passed as verbatim strings and checked against regular expressions; as such, Robert'); DROP TABLE WeeklySchedule_12_-_2021; -- would never be accepted as an entry in a field or combination of fields. This process takes place before the method containing this query string is called. Did you assume that I wouldn't give Bobby Tables his exams while building the app?

Comment: @CaiusJard For names, anyone with a name like "O'Leary" must use a variation with only letters (i.e., "OLeary"). It might be inappropriate to do this in some contexts, but for this particular app getting people's names to exactly match what is on their legal documents is not required.

Comment: That is still absolutely no excuse to write code that is prone to SQL injection hacking; doing so is [massively irresponsible](https://www.cnbc.com/amp/2015/12/02/vtech-hack-data-of-64m-kids-exposed.html)

Comment: *Did you assume that I wouldn't give Bobby Tables his exams while building the app?* - you've just told me you didn't, right there in the question.. Throw that table-with-variable-name away in favor of a table with a fixed name and an indexed date column, then you can use EF on it too

Comment: @CaiusJard If I understand EF correctly, it will not be suitable for these tables. A new one would be made each week and I would need to update the data model every time, unless there's a feature in EF that works with tables outside of the model.

Comment: Throw that table-with-variable-name away in favor of a table with a fixed name and an indexed date column, then you can use EF on it too